# Differential Equation $(D^2-1)y = e^{x}\sec^{2}x\tan x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How can I start to solve this differential equation?

$$(D^2-1)y = e^{x}\sec^{2}x\tan x$$

[Question Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLyIm.png)

Comment: What do you denote as $D^2$ ?

Comment: it's $D^2y=y''$ @Rebellos

Comment: @Aryadeva Ok, thanks! We don't use that a lot here.

Comment: It seems the particular solution to the DE has no closed form with elementary functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$(D^2-1)y = e^{x}\sec^{2}x\tan x$$
$$ r^2-1=0 \implies S_r=\{ -1,1\}$$
The solution to the homogeneous equation is:
$$y_h(x)=c_1e^x+c_2e^{-x}$$
The particular solution is:
$$y_p = \dfrac 1 {(D^2-1)} e^{x}\sec^{2}x\tan x$$
$$y_p = e^x\dfrac 1 {D(D+2)}\sec^{2}x\tan x$$
$$y_p = \dfrac {e^x}2 \left (\dfrac 1 D-\dfrac 1{D+2} \right)\sec^{2}x\tan x$$
$$y_p = \dfrac {e^x}2 \left(\int \tan xd\tan x - e^{-2x}\int e^{2x} \sec^{2}x\tan x \right)$$
$$y_p = \dfrac {e^x}4 \tan^2 x -\dfrac {e^{-x}}2  \int e^{2x} \sec^{2}x\tan x dx$$
I don't think you can evaluate the last integral with elementary functions.

Comment: Thank you sir. I'am so grateful. I have just founded the same answer but couldn't solve integral e^2x*sec^2x*tanx and I was comparing my result to Nimu Basak's result. So, Nimu Basak's answer is wrong, ısn't it?

Comment: You're welcome @SemihAtaman you can keep the integral that way in your solution.

Answer (score 0):

The solution of your problem is 
$$y=C_1e^x+C_2e^{-x}+\frac{1}{2}e^{-x}[x\tan x -x]$$
The complete solution is given in the picture[image]

Comment: @Rebellos Mate, check now, is it okay?

Comment: Thank you. I couldn't get where D-1 has gone? And how could we integrate e^x*sec^(2)x*tanx

Comment: Mate,In particular integral I used first the $\frac{1}{D-1}$then $\frac{1}{D+1}$since ,$$\frac{1}{D-m}f(x)=e^{mx}\int e^{-mx} f(x) dx$$